# py.test: ImportError: No module named mysql

Tags: python, mysql, virtualenv, pytest

I have problems running py.test over packages that imports mysql. The package mysql was installed with pip in a virtualenv.

```
# test_mysql.py

import mysql

def foo():
  pass
```

I can run without any problem `python test_mysql.py`, but when I execute `py.test test_mysql.py` I get:

```
>   import mysql
E   ImportError: No module named mysql
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

Comment: yep, that worked! What was the problem exactly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like you're using system-wide version of `py.test` which use non-virtualenv-version of python. (In which, `mysql` package is not installed).

Install `py.test` inside the virtualenv, then your problem will be solved.

---

**SIDE NOTE**

To make sure you're using the newly-installed `py.test`, clear the command path cache used by shell.

For example, if you use `bash`, issue the following command:

```
hash -r
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find @falsetru's answer doesn't work if you installed pytest system wide AFTER you installed in in the virtualenv, as I did.

(Quick note: **py.test** is the old version of the command, **pytest** is the recommended way, but what applies to one applies to the other)

You can find out where pytest is being loaded from by calling `which pytest`.

As you can see, my pytest points one that is not in the virtualenv:

```
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ which python
/home/andrew/projects/test/website/env/bin/python
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ which pytest
/home/andrew/.local/bin/pytest
```

Here's proof that pytest IS installed in the virtualenv:

```
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ pip install pytest
Requirement already satisfied: pytest in ./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.4.29 in ./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest)
```

And `hash -r` makes no difference (as no new installation happened):

```
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ hash -r
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ which pytest
/home/andrew/.local/bin/pytest
```

The solution is to uninstall and reinstall pytest in the virtualenv,

```
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ pip uninstall pytest
...
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ pip install pytest
...
(env)  ~/projects/test/website $ which pytest
/home/andrew/projects/test/website/env/bin/pytest
```

If for some reason you can't reinstall, one way to get round this is by calling pytest as a module via the python in your virtualenv:

```
python -m pytest
```